# Is it wrong to have a webpage make continuous calls to PHP -> MYSQL for updates?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm building a simple page that will be used by a small team of people. They want live updates, so when a status of a ticket on the page is changed by one user, it will update everyone's view in the browser automatically.

How I have this set up is using JQuery with AJAX repeating the call to a php page every 10 - 15 seconds. Is that bad to do?

I tried looking into more efficient methods, but I haven't really seen anything straight forward. I did come across using Node.js, but I don't have that kind of ability with our current web host.

I figured Ajax would be best via JQuery, cause the variables are the only thing that is passing back and forth. No images or graphics, or reloading the page, cause that's already displaying via HTML (obviously).

Your input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try this! https://duckduckgo.com/?q=web+sockets. AJAX isn't wrong necessarily, but it's not as scalable.

Comment: I would say that 10-15 seconds is kinda wrong... the WebSockets stuff looks interesting, but complete browser support appears limited.  Your users are asking for a real time processing solution out of a web application, which to me is what is kinda wrong.  That said, you see "polling" used quite frequently to update information (heck even this site does it).  I would keep my updates in the "minutes" category though.  If you want full duplex communication with immediate notification, perhaps you should consider a full on java swing application using sockets.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. This makes sense. I will investigate the two, but polling the server every (say) 2 minutes is okay to program in the site?

Comment: @halfer I just peaked at the Websocket method, and this seems to be a great one! Since my users are all on mostly chrome and firefox, with auto-updates, I'm sure this will easy to implement. Thanks again you guys!

Comment: I think you can get JS libraries that will use sockets if they are available and fall back to AJAX if not. I think that's how http://socket.io/ works, give it a read.